# Discrete Mathematics book for kenneth rosen manual solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request

I'm looking for the manual solution for this book

**Discrete Mathematics and its applications for Kenneth H. Rosen 7E Global edition**

[image]

Where can I find it?

Comment: I suspect that the solutions manual is legally available only to instructors who have adopted the text. You can ask here about particular exercises that puzzle you. Each time you do, show us what you tried and where you are stuck,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have some chance in this link http://www.academia.edu/7558736/Solution_Manual_of_Discrete_Mathematics_and_its_Application_by_Kenneth_H_Rosen
Of course it requires registering but finally I could download a file containing some solution. Check whether it is useful.

Comment: the file which you downloaded has the solutions for the even numbers questions because the book has the solutions for the odd numbers questions.

just wanted to inform you in case you was looking for the odd questions answers.

thank you for the link.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!!